# Uploading image to Cloudinary (Mean)

Tags: angularjs, api, upload, mean, cloudinary

This question includes particulars to a framework, but I just have the general question on how to upload the photo file to an api. What is the actual part of the image that I submitting? What is the content of the photo?

I am able to successfully upload an image upon clicking a button (using angular-file-uploader. However, I don't know what part of this object I should be sending to my api.

The code below will complain about a type error: it can't convert circular structure to JSON.

So I can also try to grab the file out of the queue, but then I when it makes it to cloudinary, I receive an error: TypeError: file.match is not a function.

html

```
<div>
    <input type="file" nv-file-select uploader="user.uploader" />
    <button ng-click="user.upload()">Upload</button> 
</div>
```

controller

```
vm.upload = function() {
    console.log(vm.uploader);
    var photo = {file: vm.uploader.queue[0]}
    UserDisplay.uploadPhoto($stateParams.user_id, vm.uploader.queue[0])
}
```

api

```
cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.body.file, function(result) {
    console.log("made it here");
    console.log(result)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Cloudinary's Angular library supports ng-file-upload, not angular-file-uploader.

There's some code that isn't displayed here. For example what is `UserDisplay`?

You get this error because queue holds FileItem objects and not strings.
You should initialize `FileUploader` with the upload url, and `formData` that includes the `upload_preset`. That way there is no need to override the upload function.

You can see the sample project on Cloudinary's AngularJS repo: https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_angular/tree/master/samples/photo_album